# Django AttributeError when attempting to save objects to database through model.py

Tags: python, django, database, model

I am working on a web-app that searches the IGDB database for games of a user chosen title, then displays them on screen. Users will be able to click an add button to add the chosen game to their personal collection as a user. Right now I am working on the database models and I am having trouble with the collections model I am building. I want to be able to save each game under a user specific collection.

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Game(models.Model):
    collector = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    storyline = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    genre_set = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
  
class Collection(models.Model):
    from .views import save
    collector = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colletion = models.ManyToOneRel(save.game_data, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
    pass


class Counter(models.Model):
    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
    def get_value(self):
        return self.counter
```

This is my saving function in views.py:

```
from igdb.wrapper import IGDBWrapper
from django.views.generic import ListView
from catolog.models import Game
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
import requests

exp_time = False

# Create your views here.
def save(request, message_json):
    from catolog.models import Counter
    # Must point to obj index from results on page
    game_data = message_json[Counter.get_value]
    game_data.save()
    return render(request, 'catolog/search_page.html')
```

And the html:

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/button.css' %}">
    <h2>Search for a game!</h2>
    <div class="search-bar" id="searchDiv">
        <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST" id="searchForm" style="left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        z-index: 100;" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" formaction="{% url 'search' %}" name="user_input" id="id_q" placeholder="Search..." >
            <!-- <button formaction="{% url 'search' %}">Sumbit</button> -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        <br>
        {% for key, game in group_games.items %}
            <fieldset class="card" style="width: 40%; margin: auto; background-color: rgba(255, 187, 0, 0.692); color: black; border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px">
                <ul>
                    {% if game.cover_url %}
                        <img src="{{ game.cover_url }}" alt="Cover Art" style="width: 200px; height: 280px;">
                    <br>
                    {% endif %}
                        <ul style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">{{ game.name }}</ul>
                    <br> 
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock content %}
                    <br>
                    <fieldset style="border-color: black;">
                        <legend style="color: black; font-weight: bolder;">Genres:</legend>
                        <ul style="font-weight: bolder; align-items: center;">{{ game.genres }}</ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </ul>
                <form action="{% url 'saveGame' %}" method="POST">
                    { counter.increment }
                    <button class="name noselect" type="submit" id="wishlistBtn">Wishlist It</button>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        {% endfor %}>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The error I am being given when making migrations is:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'game_data'

What do I need to do to save the data as a Game object? And how do I relate it back as a collection more generally?

Answer (score 1):

If me, code will be sth like this:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # name should not be null
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    storyline = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    genre_set = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
  
class Collection(models.Model):
    collector = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Game, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 


class Counter:
    counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def increment(cls):
        cls.counter += 1

    @classmethod
    def get_value(cl):
        return cls.counter
```

views.py

```
def save_collection(request, game_id):
    Counter.increment()
    # Must point to obj index from results on page
    game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
    collection, _ = Collection.objects.get_or_create(collector=request.user)
    collection.games.add(game) 
    return render(request, 'catolog/search_page.html')
```

I don't know how to change your template. May be you can get answer from document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/

Or tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/